# questions about $args on try_files inside location with regex

Tags: nginx, location, url-rewriting, args

(sorry for my bad english)

i have a URL like this:

http://www.domain.com/resize.php?pic=images/elements/imagename.jpg&type=300crop

that php checks if that image exists and serves, if not, creates image on disk with the size specified in the type parameter and returns it.

what I wanted is to check if the image exists on disk at that size, with nginx, so run only resize.php when necessary to create the image.

I tried this, but i think that location directive doesn't operate on query parameters ($args) using regex, then loncation does not match with sample URL :(

any help please?

I need to rewrite the parameters ($args) and use them in the try_files directive... is this possible?

```
location ~ "^/resize\.php\?pic=images/(elements|gallery)/(.*)\.jpg&type=([0-9]{1,3}[a-z]{0,4})$)" { 
  try_files /images/$1/$2.jpg /imagenes/elements/thumbs/$3_$2.jpg @phpresize;
}

location @phpresize {
  try_files $uri =404;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_buffering on;
  proxy_pass http://www.localhost.com:8080;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match query string in `location` (e.g., see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/237517/nginx-query-keyword-matching-in-location) and [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,70190,70376)). The only way to process requests differently depending on the query string contents is to use `if` and conditional rewrites.

However, if it is OK to handle requests to `/resize.php` which do not have expected query parameters using the `@phpresize` location config, you can try something like this:

```
map $arg_pic $image_dir {
    # A subdirectory with this name should not exist.
    default invalid;

    ~^images/(?P<img_dir>elements|gallery)/.*\.jpg$      $img_dir;
}

map $arg_pic $image_name {
    # The ".*" match here might be insecure - using something like "[-a-z0-9_]+"
    # would probably be better if it matches all your image names;
    # choose a regexp which is appropriate for your situation.
    ~^images/(elements|gallery)/(?P<img_name>.*)\.jpg$   $img_name;
}

map $arg_type $image_type {
    ~^(?P<img_type>[0-9]{1,3}[a-z]{0,4})$    $img_type;
}

location ~ "^/resize.php$" {
    try_files /images/${image_dir}/${image_name}.jpg /imagenes/elements/thumbs/${image_type}_${image_name}.jpg @phpresize;
}

location @phpresize {
    # No changes from your config here.
    try_files $uri =404;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_pass http://www.localhost.com:8080;
}
```